# Change all entities for some collection (Robo3t)

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

Is it possible to get all entities in 1 file , change some words there update all this entities in db ?

[image]

Imagine I have a lot of entities , this entities have some text field, it can be at different level, etc different prop names, and I don't want to move inside each entity change it and then save it , I want to open all this entities in 1 file , match text which I need , replace it , and then update all this entities in db , is there possible way for this ?

Comment: You can issue an update query.

Comment: Could you show some example ? As I understand update query work by some property name , but I don't have particular property name , it can be any deep , any name , etc @D.SM, this is why I need to get all data in 1 file , match values, change it and update

Comment: Then you can export the entire collection, edit it and import?

Comment: Can I make it inside of Robo3T ? or only by using terminal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a quick and dirty way in robo 3t

write following query

```
db.getCollection('pages').find({}).toArray()
```

and `right click` + `Copy JSON`

[image]

and paste in a text editor, after editing, you can use import json with `command` or using `insertMany([])` but if you using `insertMany`, every time just 16Mb can insert into collection

Comment: it's a simple query, why do you have a error?? use `.limit()  `like this : `db.getCollection('pages').find({}).limit(100).toArray()` and check do you have any error again?

Comment: increased timeout , and it works now) reloaded robo3t )

Comment: I've created a related issue @Mohammad , could you pls check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66116286/insertmany-return-writecommanderror-not-master-robo3t ?